# Firebase authentication and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, devise, firebase-authentication

I have a question, I am trying to make a session with the gem devise, but at the same time create the session in firebase to be able to save the data and use the file storage, so far I have been able to do so, but at the moment Of closing session and want to start session again, no longer does the connection to firebase.

```js
  $("#inicioUser").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("funciono");
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
   
    var ses = sessionEmail(email,password);
    return ses 
    
    
  });
  
  var sessionEmail = function sessionEmail(email,password){
   return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  if (errorMessage) {
      errorRegister(errorMessage);
      return false;
  }else{
   success();
   return true;
  }
 
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<%= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), :html => {:id => "inicioUser"} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :id => 'email' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :id => 'password' %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <button id="logInForm" >Inciar sesion</button>
    
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to call the success function when no error is caught?

Without delving too deeply into it myself I would guess that the problem is that when you catch the Firebase error there will probably always be an error message (even if empty), so it never reaches the success function. This is my guess.

If you put your success function into a `then()` part of the promise the success function will be called when there are no errors. If there are errors it should not be called, which I'm guessing is what you were trying for. I might be wrong but I hope that is some help.

```
var sessionEmail = function sessionEmail(email,password){
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function() {
      success();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      errorRegister(error.message);
    });
};
```